# A neater way to count survey responses from mysql db

Tags: php, mysql, survey

currently I using this code to count survey responses:

```
$VERYHAPPY = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM answers, complete WHERE (answers.uniqueID = complete.uniqueID) AND (complete.timestamp) IS NOT NULL AND (answers.surveyID='$surveyID') AND QID = '$QID' AND response = 'VERY HAPPY' ");
$HAPPY = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM answers, complete WHERE (answers.uniqueID = complete.uniqueID) AND (complete.timestamp) IS NOT NULL AND (answers.surveyID='$surveyID') AND QID = '$QID' AND response = 'HAPPY' ");
$DONTKNOW = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM answers, complete WHERE (answers.uniqueID = complete.uniqueID) AND (complete.timestamp) IS NOT NULL AND (answers.surveyID='$surveyID') AND QID = '$QID' AND response = 'DONT KNOW' ");
$UNHAPPY = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM answers, complete WHERE (answers.uniqueID = complete.uniqueID) AND (complete.timestamp) IS NOT NULL AND (answers.surveyID='$surveyID') AND QID = '$QID' AND response = 'UNHAPPY' ");
$VERYUNHAPPY = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM answers, complete WHERE (answers.uniqueID = complete.uniqueID) AND (complete.timestamp) IS NOT NULL AND (answers.surveyID='$surveyID') AND QID = '$QID' AND response = 'VERY UNHAPPY' ");

 $VERYHAPPYcount = mysql_num_rows($VERYHAPPY);
 $HAPPYcount = mysql_num_rows($HAPPY);
 $DONTKNOWcount = mysql_num_rows($DONTKNOW); 
 $UNHAPPYcount = mysql_num_rows($UNHAPPY);
 $VERYUNHAPPYcount = mysql_num_rows($VERYUNHAPPY); 
  echo "VERY HAPPY = $VERYHAPPYcount</br>HAPPY = $HAPPYcount</br>DON'T KNOW = $DONTKNOWcount</br>UNHAPPY = $UNHAPPYcount</br>VERY UNHAPPY = $VERYUNHAPPYcount";
```

as you can see - it's really messy! Any better way to do this? I've tried COUNT and GROUP BY, but can't get them to work. Thanks

Comment: As a side note, I'd recommend looking into the PDO functions in PHP.  A small learning curve (about the same as the one you're on now) and a big increase in flexibility. http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/

Comment: What information *are* you getting back? Have you tried `var_dump` or `printr` on your result object(s) to see what you're getting back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this SQL (which I haven't tested) -

```
SELECT count(*) as recordcount, response 
FROM answers, complete 
WHERE (answers.uniqueID = complete.uniqueID) 
AND (complete.timestamp) IS NOT NULL 
AND (answers.surveyID='$surveyID') 
AND QID = '$QID'
GROUP BY response
```

To get the results into PHP you could try something like this (I can't test PHP code so I've based the code below on this code - http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php and hoped for the best! The code below will almost certainly contain errors but will hopefully give you an idea of how it could be done)

```
//assign sql above to $query variable prior to doing this
$result = mysql_query($query);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo $row['response'] & " = " & $ row['recordcount'] & "count</br>"
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this - however I'm unsure how I would print/echo the results?

Comment: I've edited the answer and had a go at explaining how you might be able to do it